# Trouble with Async/Await on APIs response

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, async-await

Hey guys that's my first app using Node.js and I'm having trouble working with **async/ await.**
On my index.js I have three methods that depends on each-other, but can't figure out how to do it.

Can someone lend me a hand and teach me in in the work?

```
async function Millennium_SendSMS() {

    // search for orders on Millennium's API
    let orders = await new listOrders().listOrders();

    // filter orders
    let filteredOrders = new filterOrders().filterOrders(orders);

    // send sms to the filtered orders
    filteredOrders.map(order => {
        new sendSmsRequest(order).sendSmsRequest();
    })
}
```

When I try to run the code above, I get an error message from the **filterOrders** method saying that that the var orders is **undefined**.

Update:

listOrders class

```
class listOrders {

    listOrders() {

        axios.get('http://mill.com/api/millenium_eco/pedido_venda/listapedidos')

            .then(listOrders => {

                return listOrders;
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your current code. Do you receive errors. Can you elaborate on what problem you are facing

Comment: Definitely! I'm updating the thread.

Comment: You'll have to show us the code behind `new listOrders().listOrders()`.  Also, that is a bizarre looking API.  Class names should at least start with a capital letter and rarely does a method have the exact same name as the class.

Comment: I'll fix that right away.

Comment: You need to return the result of the axios.get function

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned the promise from listOrders function within your class so there is nothing to resolve for the await function

Add a return statement to listOrders function like below and it would work

```
class listOrders {

    listOrders() {

        return axios.get('http://mill.com/api/millenium_eco/pedido_venda/listapedidos')

            .then(listOrders => {

                return listOrders;
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason it's still returning undefined.

Comment: Is you API correct. Do you see any error in console

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If I console log the result (inside ListOrders class) it is just fine. If I console log orders on the index.js, it is undefined.